# Applying an arbitrary sort to Django ORM querysets

Tags: python, sql, django, sorting, orm

I have a database table containing sets of items representing yearly recurring events. The record sets are stored by month and day. I often need to retrieve the event records corresponding to a range of calendar dates. I'm using the Django ORM to work with the records, so at present I convert the dates to corresponding `Q` objects (e.g. `Q(month=month, day=day)` and OR them together in the call to `MyModel.objects.filter()`.

The problem comes if my date range intersects the new year. If I want the events from Dec. 31, 2013 to Jan 1, 2014, I do something like:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(Q(month=12, day=31) | Q(month=1, day=1))
```

But I get my results in the order:

```
month = 1, day = 1
month = 12, day = 31
```

Instead, I would like to get my results in the order:

```
month = 12, day = 31
month = 1, day = 1
```

For reasons that would unnecessarily complicate the question, I *can't* simply partition the query into two queries, one for each year. I would like to make one query and get the results in the desired order. I *can* reformulate the query, if necessary.

I know that `extra` should be useful, but I don't quite see how to use it.

**Update:**

To head a little closer to the intended solution, to impose an absolute ordering I could somehow slip the [Julian Day](http://klenwell.com/press/2011/05/julian-day-in-python/) into the results as a "calculated" field, and order by that field. But how to do that?

Comment: Is there a `year` field?

Comment: No, or this would be trivial. :) These records represent events that recur from year to year.

Comment: is Join allowed in this query? (I mean will it affect performance much?)

Comment: I don't see why not. I'm willing to at least try it.

Comment: Does the range always spans two months, or can it have an arbitrary length?

Comment: @LudwikTrammer Arbitrary length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tricky solution Using `extra` and SQL `CASE` statement:

```
start_month = 12
start_day = 31
end_month = 1
end_day = 1
query = (models.MyModel.objects.filter(Q(month=start_month, day=start_day) | 
                                       Q(month=end_month, day=end_day))
                       .extra(select={'order_me': '''CASE WHEN month*31+day < %s*31+%s 
                                                          THEN (12+month)*31+day 
                                                          ELSE (month)*31+day
                                                   END''' % (start_month, start_day)})
                       .extra(order_by=['order_me']))
```

As soon as I have added this `order_me` field (which is not nice) I think It should be used  in predicate instead of `Q(...)|Q(...)` for date range

```
query = (models.MyModel.objects.all()
                   .extra(select={'order_me': """CASE WHEN month*31+day < %s*31+%s 
                                                    THEN (12+month)*31+day 
                                                    ELSE (month)*31+day
                                               END""" % (start_month, start_day) })
                   .extra(order_by=['order_me'])
                   .extra(where=['order_me < (12 + %s) * 31 + %s' % (end_month,
                                                                     end_day)]))
```

Comment: Tricky indeed. But won't `month*31+day` always be less than `12*31+31`?

Comment: no sometimes it is equal, but You are right I have fixed this

Comment: Yeah, that second formulation looks right, and about as dirty as I would expect. :)

Comment: You answered my question as posed, which is very helpful. :) I have other, more complex requirements which make this solution unworkable for my particular case, but this at least helps me rule out SQL as the place to do all that I need.

Comment: There are more than one solution for You issue, maybe If You tell me details I will propose You something better.